# How to integrate a modal dialog

Tags: jquery

I want to show AJAX error messages for form validation and want these messages centered on the screen. I was advised to use a modal window for this. I have the following code but I'm not sure how to do this. I know that I need to call the modal in the success function but unfortunately that's about the extent of my JQ knowledge.

This is my JQ script where the modal should be integrated

```
  success: function(data){
    ...
    if(data.success == 0){
      $(div).addClass('ajax-error');
    }
```

This is the modal code. This code is currently set up to work with a hyperlink that activates the window but I don't need that. The window should be invoked automatically upon error in the code above.

```
  $('a[name=modal]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('href');

    var maskHeight = $(document).height();
    var maskWidth = $(window).width();

    $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

    $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);
    $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

    var winH = $(window).height();
    var winW = $(window).width();

    $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
    $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

    $(id).fadeIn(2000);
  });

  $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#mask').hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });

  $('#mask').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.window').hide();
  });
```

Comment: try this one: http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal

Comment: as Oliver suggested, I would use a third party component. Much easier.

Comment: Hi Oliver, thanks for the link. I've already looked at that one but it doesn't look like it will fade in and out. It also has the traditional "X" to close the box and all I'm looking for is a way to fade in and out these messages without the user having to click anything. The main reason for the modal is to center these messages on the screen

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the jQuery [Model Dialog Plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/modaldialog).

The documentation is a bit sparse, but the [demo page](http://tautologistics.com/projects/jquery.modaldialog/doc/1.0.0/) and your friends Firefox and FireBug will paint a pretty complete picture.

It has the AutoClose feature you want.

The plugin applies an opaque mask and has DIV styles such as "dialog-header," "dialog-title," and "dialog-close" to allow you to style the appearance.

Comment: Thanks BJ, I'll look into this solution.

Comment: Hey BJ, can I use this solution and just simply call the modal from my success function? Am I correct in saying that this solution will be that easy?

Comment: That easy. Be sure to include the plugin's CSS and JS files. You may want to edit the CSS to better match your look, but other than that, yes.